# Remove two int from three consecutive values from List<int>

Tags: c#, list, numbers

I use Winforms and C#. And I have more than 300 integers in a list and this is short example:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(4);
lst.Add(25);
lst.Add(26);
lst.Add(27);
lst.Add(38);
lst.Add(51);
lst.Add(52);
lst.Add(53);
lst.Add(75);
//Etc.
```

I need to remove values (25, 26) but keep 27. Then again remove values (51, 52) but keep 53.. etc.

So basically if three consecutive values such as (1, 2, 3) are found, we need to remove (1, 2) and keep value (3).

As far as attempts are concerned, I couldn't scratch my head around any solution so far therefore I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: @Aomine ofc just made a typo mistake while writing the example. Fixed it

Comment: Alright, I've edited the post.

Comment: @Dai Thanks! let me give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Start removing from the end of the list and work towards the beginning.  When you remove item 25, all the items afterwards decrease by one so your delete items move.  If you start at the end and work towards the beginning then the deletes should work

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more. What about duplicates (there are 2 occurrences of 4)? What should be done if there are more than 3 incremented values (remove n-1 and just keep n)?

Comment: @UNOPARATOR I have editted the post. There shouldnt be any dupplicates since i distinct them into a new list. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: @jdweng item 25 is just an example. Numbers could be randomly generated and the list is huge too.

Comment: Deleting an index number from a list is very quick.  The slow part is to locate a string in the list.  The average time to locate an item in a list is N/2 where N is the number of items in the list.  To reduce the time of locating the item you would need to create a hash (a dictionary uses a hash) to locate the key which then will take Log(N) to locate a string in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following. The key is marking the items to remove by detecting the sequence and picking the first two.

```
var excludeList = lst.Distinct()
                     .GroupBy(num => 
                                 Enumerable.Range(num, int.MaxValue - num + 1)
                                 .TakeWhile(lst.Contains)
                                 .Last()) 
                     .Where(seq => seq.Count() >= 3)
                     .SelectMany(seq => seq.OrderBy(num => num).Take(2));


var result = lst.Where(x=> !excludeList.Contains(x));
```

**Output**

```
4 
27 
38 
53 
75
```

Comment: Beautiful & Efficient! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    static void Test()
    {
      var list = new List<int>();
      list.Add(4);
      list.Add(25);
      list.Add(26);
      list.Add(27);
      list.Add(38);
      list.Add(51);
      list.Add(52);
      list.Add(53);
      list.Add(75);
```

```
      var result = new List<int>();
      int count = list.Count;
      bool passover;
      if ( count > 0 )
        for ( int index = 0; index < count; )
        {
          passover = false;
          if ( index < count - 3 )
          {
            int v1 = list[index];
            int v2 = list[index + 1];
            int v3 = list[index + 2];
            if ( v3 == v2 + 1 && v2 == v1 + 1 )
              passover = true;
          }
          if ( passover )
          {
            result.Add(list[index + 2]);
            index += 3;
          }
          else
          {
            result.Add(list[index]);
            index++;
          }
        }
```

```
      foreach ( var item in result )
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Output:

```
4
27
38
53
75
```

Comment: Not in the OOP.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try then mark your answer if it works.

Comment: Answer updated to use ints instead of strings of your original question.

Comment: Works like a charm! And the logic itself is better than I had in mind.Thank you